# Searching one pandas DataFrame column based on the search criteria made up of the content of two columns for another df separated by a wild card

Tags: python, pandas, string, search, wildcard

I want to lookup the value of a the lookup_table value column based on the combination of text and two different columns from the data table. See example below:

Data:

| VMType | Location |
| --- | --- |
| DSv3 | East Europe |
| ESv3 | East US |
| ESv3 | East Asia |
| DSv4 | Central US |
| Ca2 | Central US |

lookup_table:

| Type | Code |
| --- | --- |
| Dv3/DSv3 - Gen Purpose East Europe | abc123 |
| Dv3/D1 - Gen Purpose West US | abc321 |
| Dav4/DSv4 - Gen Purpose Central US | bbb321 |
| Eav3/ESv3 - Hi Tech East Asia | def321 |
| Eav3/ESv3 - Hi Tech East US | xcd321 |
| Csv2/Ca2 - Hi Tech Central US | xcc321 |

I want to do something like

```
data['new_column'] = lookup_table['Code'] where lookup_table['Type'] == Data['VMType'] + '*' + Data['Location']
```

or to remove the wild card it could be evaluated as follows:

```
data['new_column'] = lookup_table['Code'] where lookup_table['Type'] contains Data['VMType'] AND lookup_table['Type'] contains Data['Location']
```

Resulting in:

Data:

| VMType | Location | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DSv3 | East Europe | abc123 |
| ESv3 | East US | xcd321 |
| ESv3 | East Asia | def321 |
| DSv4 | Central US | abc321 |
| Ca2 | Central US | xcc321 |

Ideally this can be done without iterating through the df.

Comment: does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

First, extract columns `VMType` and `Location` from the `lookup_table`. Then merge with your `data` dataframe:

```
lookup_table['VMType'] = lookup_table['Type'].str[:2]
lookup_table['Location'] = lookup_table['Type'].str.split().str[-1]
lookup_table = lookup_table[['VMType', 'Location', 'Code']]

data.merge(lookup_table)
```

Output:

```
  VMType Location    Code
0     D1   Europe  abc123
1     E3       US  xcd321
2     E3     Asia  def321
3     D1       US  abc321
4     C2       US  xcc321
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and I had not anticipated using string splitting when formulating my sample tables. So I have now updated them to closer reflect the real world challenge. I think I effectively need some type of contains evaluation in combination with an 'AND or &' but don't know if this is possible. A lookup using concatenation of two different cells with and * in the middle is simple in Excel but can't find a way of doing it in Pandas.